# LEFT JOIN 3rd Table to the original Table rather than the resultant table

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join

I have two tables such as

1. Income(point, date, inc)
2. Outcome(point, date, out)

where *point* and *date* are the primary key. 
I need to find out the total income `inc` and outcome `out` on any given date.
My answer

```
WITH all_date AS
(SELECT point, date FROM income
UNION
SELECT point, date FROM outcome)
SELECT a.point, a.date, SUM(inc), SUM(out)
FROM all_date a LEFT JOIN income i ON i.point=a.point AND i.date=d.date
                LEFT JOIN outcome o ON o.point=a.point AND o.date=a.date
GROUP BY a.point, a.date
```

But I am getting wrong result. Because the `all_date LEFT JOIN income` while trying to do `LEFT JOIN` with `outcome` duplicates certain rows from `income`, hence messing with the final `SUM`.

Basically I want to `LEFT JOIN` the third table `outcome` with `all_date` **not with** `all_date LEFT JOIN income`. Refer to Qus No 30. of http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php for further clarification

Answer (score 4):

Why not do that join first then?

or even better, just do a full outer join:

```
Select coalesce(o.point, i.point) point,
   coalesce(o.Date, i.date) date
From income i full join outcome o
  on o.point=i.point 
     and o.date=i.date
group by coalesce(o.point, i.point),
     coalesce(o.Date, i.date)
```

and, since you're not actually using any aggregation functions, a distinct would work as well:

```
Select distinct
   coalesce(o.point, i.point) point,
   coalesce(o.Date, i.date) date
From income i full join outcome o
  on o.point=i.point 
     and o.date=i.date
```

My apologies, I'm not a MySQL guy and did not realize that MySQL does not have Full Join syntax.  but there is a workaround. look at the following link:

[Full Join in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

basically you need a Union, (close to what you were doing, actually)

```
select point, date 
from income i
 left join outcome o 
    on o.point=i.point 
      and o.date=i.date  
  UNION                 -- <-- leave out the ALL to eliminate duplicates
select point, date 
from outcome o
 right join income i 
    on i.point=o.point 
      and i.date=o.date
```

Comment: Just realized MySQL doesn't support FULL JOIN. Any solution for that?

Comment: My apologies, I'm not a MySQL guy and did not realize that. But check this out... as mentioned in link in my answer

Comment: @BikashBehera don't confuse people - you tagged tour question with MS SQL SERVER dbms.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes, sorry about that. I actually tagged with both MSSQL and MySQL as the exercise is in MSSQL and I was trying to solve the exercise on my PC with MySQL. Then the initial question editor removed the mysql tag later on.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is the purpose of using table expression here, you can get the result by using one join here:

```
SELECT i.point, i.date, SUM(inc), SUM(out)
FROM  income i 
LEFT JOIN outcome o   
ON o.point=i.point AND o.date=i.date
GROUP BY i.point, i.date
```

Comment: uni-directional outer join will skip rows in one side.

Comment: @LONG in your query you will drop out the rows from right table `outcome` which has no match in left table `income`. To get all the `point-date` I used the CTE

Comment: I see, then use `INNER JOIN` if you only want to filter out those common date. Just change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` in my answer. And, based on your comment, I am guessing you do not want to miss any date no matter there exists both `inc` and `out`, then try :  SELECT i.point, i.date, SUM(ISNULL(i.inc,0)), SUM(ISNULL(o.out,0))
FROM  income i 
FULL JOIN outcome o   
ON o.point=i.point AND o.date=i.date
GROUP BY i.point, i.date

Answer (score 0):

**MS-SQL sp for your problem:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dototals
@date DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

SELECT point,SUM(ISNULL(inc,0)) as inc into #tmp_i FROM Income WHERE date =@date  GROUP BY point

SELECT point,SUM(ISNULL(out,0)) as out into #tmp_d FROM Outcome WHERE date =@date  GROUP BY point

SELECT DISTINCT point into #tmp_p FROM 
(SELECT point FROM #tmp_i
UNION ALL
SELECT point FROM #tmp_o)

SELECT @date as date, t1.point as point, t2.out as outcome,t3.inc as income 
FROM #tmp_p as t1
LEFT JOIN #tmp_o as t2 on t1.point=t2.point
LEFT JOIN #tmp_i as t3 on t1.point=t3.point
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution in MSSQL. But I guess using `COALESCE` with `FULL JOIN` works the best.

```
    WITH all_date AS
    (SELECT point, date FROM income
    UNION
    SELECT point, date FROM outcome)

    SELECT a.point, a.date,
    (SELECT SUM(o.out) FROM outcome o WHERE o.point=a.point AND o.date=a.date) AS outcome,
    (SELECT SUM(i.inc) FROM income i WHERE i.point=a.point AND i.date=a.date) AS income

    FROM all_date a
```